# I'm unsure which of two variables should be my dependent/independent variables?

Tags: regression, experiment-design, predictor

Let's say I have 100 different samples of child speech. Let's say I want to see if children use more abstract words later on. Let's say I also want to control for the length of the words. (These aren't my real research questions, but comparable examples.)

For each sample of child speech I take the the average abstractness of the words uttered. I also take the average length of the words uttered. I also have the age the child was at the time. So I have data like this below:

```
a <- c("Sample",    "Age",  "Avg. Abstractness","Avg. Length")
b <- c(1,   12, 3.2,    3.4)
c <- c(2,   14, 3.5,    1.1)
d <- rbind(a,b,c)
View(d)
```

What I am confused about is whether it makes sense to have age be a predictor, or the dependent variable? I can imagine two potential models:

m1: Age = Abstractness + Length

m2: Abstractness = Age + Length

My initial thought was m1, but after trying to graph it, m2 seems more intuitive.

Thanks!

Comment: *"I want to see if children use more abstract words later on ... I also want to control for the length of the words"*. So abstraction is the dependent variable

Answer (score 0):

Age is exogenously given, i.e. children do not grow up by choosing to speak more abstractly. Contrary, I assume that length and abstractness are some function of age. Thus, m1 suffers from reverse causality, i.e. the "dependent variable" influences the "independent variable" and not the other way around.
Depending on how strong the correlation between and age and length is, m2 might suffer from collinearity.